# LINQ to XML Axis properties returning an attribute when selecting an element using a different attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Code block four (below) is giving me an error that I am at a loss with regard to fixing...

Here's the XML Schema that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

<!DOCTYPE ctqcfg SYSTEM "cache.dtd">

<cache version="1.0">
    <configuration name="Test">
        <cacheControl>
            <cache name="Customer" mode="off"/>
            <cache name="Vendor" mode="off"/>
            <cache name="Agency" mode="off"/>
            <cache name="Partner" mode="off"/>
        </cacheControl>
    </configuration>

    <configuration name="Production">
        <cacheControl>
            <cache name="Customer" mode="preload"/>
            <cache name="Vendor" mode="dynamic"/>
            <cache name="Agency" mode="dynamic"/>
            <cache name="Partner" mode="dynamic"/>
        </cacheControl>
    </configuration>
</cache>
```

The XML file is loaded

```
Private XElement As XElement = Nothing

Public Sub Load()
    XElement = XElement.Load(ConfigurationResource)
End Sub
```

When the user selects a configuration to edit, a reference to the root of the selected configuration element is held

```
Private ConfigurationRoot As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement)

Private ConfigurationName_ As String

Public Property ConfigurationName() As String
    Get
        Return ConfigurationName_
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        ConfigurationName_ = Value
        ConfigurationRoot = From Configuration In XElement.<configuration> Where Configuration.@name = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Trying to retrieve the cache mode that corresponds to the cache name (in this case Customer)

```
Public Property CustomerCache() As String
    Get
        Try
            Return From Cache In ConfigurationRoot.<cacheControl>.<cache> Where Cache.@name = "Customer" Select Cache.@mode
        Catch Exception As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        'ToDo
    End Set
End Property
```

I'm getting the following error

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.String'.
```

This is my first day working with LINQ and I seem to have a basic misunderstanding regarding how to access the attribute - it seems that the query is returning a collection and I know that there is only ever one possible value that can be found...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.First()` or `.Single()`:

```
Return (From Cache In ConfigurationRoot.<cacheControl>.<cache> Where Cache.@name = "Customer" Select Cache.@mode).First()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first three code blocks all achieve the same result, but with slightly different approaches to accessing the content of an attribute:

## 1. The direct return of the first (and only) instance of the "encrypted" attribute:

```
Return "true" = (From DBConnections In Configurations.<dbConnection> Where "Customization" = DBConnections.@name Select DBConnections.<password>.@encrypted).Single
```

## 2. The query a collection of XElements and then pull the "encrypted" attribute from the first XElement approach:

```
Dim Element As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = (From DBConnections In Configurations.<dbConnection> Where "Customization" = DBConnections.@name Select DBConnections.<password>).Single
Return "true" = Element(0).@encrypted
```

The previous example gently misleads us because the .Single reference explicitly states that there will be one and only one found - but in reality we must deal with a result that is a collection (with only one item). It's even more confusing when compared with approach 1 where we don't have to explicitly deal with the collection to retrieve the attribute value.

## 3a. The query a the first XElement from the collection and then pull the "encrypted" attribute approach:

```
Dim Element As XElement = ((From DBConnections In Configurations.<dbConnection> Where "Customization" = DBConnections.@name Select DBConnections.<password>).Single)(0)
Return "true" = Element.@encrypted
```

This last example endeavors to deal with the misleading part of having to deal with a collection (of one item) to the retrieval of an item within the collection as soon as possible by referencing the first item in the collection and storing it within the appropriate type so that we can stop worrying about the collection and instead deal with the object that we are really interested in (in this case a XElement object).

## 3b. Altering the "encrypted" attribute within the first XElement object

```
Dim Element As XElement = ((From DBConnections In Configurations.<dbConnection> Where "Customization" = DBConnections.@name Select DBConnections.<password>).Single)(0)
If Value Then
    Element.@encrypted = "true"
Else
    Element.@encrypted = "false"
End If
```

Working through the three query approaches helped to clarify my mental model regarding what was being returned by LINQ. Additionally, I needed to understand what was really going on here to modify the "encrypted" attribute...